# (Google AutoML) Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unsupported payload type `row`

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-automl, automl

I'm trying to port a Python function to javascript that runs a prediction model created on Google Cloud.

Everything works perfectly, until calling the `.predict()` method as it always throws an `Unsupported payload type row` error message.

The format of the payload is quite simple:

```
const data = [ { key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3 ... } ];
```

In case it helps, here's a portion of the code:

```
const {PredictionServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/automl').v1beta1;

const ai = new PredictionServiceClient({
    projectId: projectId
});
const payload = {
    row: {
        values: data
    }
};
const request = {
    name: ai.modelPath(projectId, computeRegion, modelId),
    payload: payload,
    params: {feature_importance: true}
};
const [result] = await ai.predict(request);
```

And here's the original Python code from which the js version is based on:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

aiplatform.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location=compute_region)
endpoint = aiplatform.Endpoint(ENDPOINT_ID)
response = endpoint.predict(instances=data)
```

Please let me know if I should provide any additional information.
Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think I have figured it out... in the js version I'm using the `PredictionServiceClient` from the `automl`, but in the Python version the client should be from the `aiplatform`

Comment: Hello, well as show in the [official documented files](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-predictions-automl#api) thats the client used for predictions. were you able to port after your change?

Comment: Yes... after switching to the `apiplatform` package and re-formatting the payload as a `structValue` everything is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Its good to know that you were able to solve your issue. I'm leaving this answer of the current aiplatform libraries in use as **November 2021** for the community.

- [Python AIPlatform](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/index.html)
- [NodeJs AIPlatform](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest)